oauth2-custom-policy - Custom Policy Transform Extension
We have deployed oauth2-custom-policy compatible with Java17 into exchange. And configured oauth2-custom-policy in API Manager. But while deploying our API which is using oauth2-custom-policy in API Manager getting below error.
`Error loading: /opt/mule/mule-4.6-java17/policies/oauth2-custom-policy-6242769/policy.xml, Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/**mule-http.xsd**, A dependency or plugin might be missing.
I am sharing important elements as below, we have added below dependency in POM.xml for oauth2-custom-policy
com.mulesoft.anypointmule-http-policy-transform-extension${http.policy.transform.extension}mule-plugin
org.mule.connectorsmule-http-connector
<http.policy.transform.extension>3.2.0</http.policy.transform.extension><mule.maven.plugin.version>4.2.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
remaining all properties in POM.xml are correct.
And there is no issue with Mule API as API alone deploying successfully if I don't enable oauth2-custom-policy in API Manager for this API.
Please let me know if I need to provide further details here to get solution ?

Use [code block] format for  all code, logs and errors. Specially XML which is not correctly displayed otherwise. But what you shared is insufficient. Edit the question to add a [MRE].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

http.policy.transform.extension is an enterprise edition plugin so I hope you have Maven settings file and Nexus EE repo properly set up for your project.
If yes, then
As per as error, it seems policy.xml does not recognize HTTP schema and it might be because you don't have it as When a policy using the HTTP Policy Transform Extension is packaged, the Mule HTTP Connector is unnecessarily added to the policy JAR file.
So make sure to exclude it and try it
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-http-policy-transform-extension</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
          <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>

